# How to disable Autoscroll to top in a QTableView when the underlying model changes?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have created my own class that derives from QTableView, the associated model is is derived from QAbstractTableModel. The data in the model is performance data(process name, mem usage etc.) which continuously gets updated with a short interval.

Updating the model is done by first removing all data (enclosed with a beginRemoveRows/endRemoveRows) and then "readding" the slightly changed data as a batch operation (enclosed with beginInsertRows/endInsertRows).

How do I disable the vertical autoscrolling to the top whenever I clear/readd?

Comment: Please post as an answer

Comment: No, copy your working solution from the question to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working solution**

The scrollbar movement was due to signalling removing of all data using **beginRemoveRows/endRemoveRows**. In order to avoid this I instead emitted a **dataChanged(...)** signal with the start/stop indexes of the updated list of items if it was smaller than the existing model, and with indexes from the existing model if the updated list was bigger. I also used a **begin/endRemoveRows** if the updated list was smaller and a **begin/endInsertRows** if the updated list was bigger.